# What objects are passed into the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm guessing all objects that are local to the action are passed into the view?

I never see sample code that actually specifies which objects are passed to the view!

Is it good practice to create a 'model' object and then assign, as properties to the 'model' object, all objects you want to pass to the view?

How can you explicitly pass objects?

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer if any of these answers were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you put in an instance variable (e.g., `@my_variable`) in the controller action is accessible to the view.

As far as passing model objects goes, just pass a model if you need to. But there's no need to create a "view model" object like (say) ASP.NET MVC pretty much makes you do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's all instance attribute of Controller to pass to view

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways in which you can access them. If you are just using something like
`render :template`, you are pretty much ok with having any instance variable(something that looks like `@object`). If you are say rendering partials, you can pass in as `render :partial => 'x', :locals => {:object_name => local_variable}`. The guides on rubyonrails site has pretty much what is required to do rendering on views -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html